# Can't figure out what is missing in this code

Tags: reactjs

I am working on this component here https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-paper-zsy7u?file=/src/list.js that displays item by category, but I can't seem to figure out what is missing to actually have the products show. I am sure I am missing something small, but a second set of eyes would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to send `displayCategory` props from `Mains` to `UI` components:

```js
const Mains = ({ products, productCategories }) => {
  const [displayCategory, setDisplayCategory] = useState("all");
  const setCategory = (category) => {
    setDisplayCategory(category);
  };

  return (
    <UI
      setCategory={setCategory}
      productCategories={productCategories}
      products={products}
      // HERE
      displayCategory={displayCategory}
    />
  );
};
```

And from `UI` to `ProductItems` component.

```js
                                                     //HERE
const UI = ({ state, productCategories, setCategory, displayCategory, products }) => {
  return (
    <div className="box flex-row">
      <div className="box flex-col">
        <h3>Filter by Category</h3>
        {ButtonCategories(productCategories, setCategory)}
      </div>
      <div className="box flex-col">
        <h3>Results</h3>
                       // HERE
        <ProductItems displayCategory={displayCategory} state={state} products={products} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: ahhh thank you, i appreciate your help! I think i was staring at it too long.